# How to scroll to specific section in UITableView (or ListView of android) and update on bar?

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, android-listview

I want to scroll to a specific section and update the status selected on a bar like a tab in TableView

[image]

So when I select "11/2013" on the tab or scroll down to the "11/2013" section, it would update the status according to what is selected:

[image]

Comment: What did you try so far? Something like handlers to the list's and the bar's "current element changed" events appear to be able to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this method of UITableView

```
 - (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated;
 //indexPath (row,section)
```